# Where can I buy Compute Units?

Tags: hardware, compute-module

I see a lot of media hype surrounding [Raspberry Pi Compute Units](http://www.raspberrypi.org/raspberry-pi-compute-module-new-product/) circa April 2014, but to my surprise, I can find no websites (even Ada Fruit) that actually sell them.

Additionally, because I can't find anyone that's selling them, I can't find basic info about them beyond what that high-level, lofty article announces. **What processor(s) are running on the Compute Unit? What are its other hardware specs?**

Comment: seems that in 2016 these have been discontinued and are now being scalped.

Comment: Note that of 2017 , the Compute Module 3 exists. The original CM might've become rare because of that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not finding anything because you're searching for "Raspberry Pi Compute *Units*".  They're not called that in the article you linked, or anywhere else.

You need to search for "Raspberry Pi Compute **Modules**".  You should get hits for Newark/Element 14, etc., and you'll also find them on Adafruit using that search term.

- [Google search](https://www.google.ca/?gws_rd=ssl#q=raspberry+pi+compute+module)
- [Hit from Adafruit search](http://www.adafruit.com/products/2231)

Comment: Thanks @goldilocks (+1) - but still not seeing anything on hardware specs besides the electrical schematic. I see its an ARM processor, but what size/speed? Thanks again!

Comment: @smeeb Exact same spaces as the Pi Model B - just in a different form-factor. The SOC is the exact same between the Pi and the Compute Module AFAIK. Here's a [link to Broadcom's page for the BCM285 SoC](http://www.broadcom.com/products/BCM2835).

Comment: @smeeb Np :) Just helping expand on the answer.